# why is there no research on machine learning algorithms to determine optimal hyperparameters for metaheuristics?

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter-tuning, performance, hyperparameter, metaheuristics

I am not shure if I am in the correct forum for this question. I'm sorry, if I'm in the wrong place here.

**Question:**

*Why is there no research on machine learning algorithms to determine hyperparameters for metaheuristics*? So far, I have only been able to find papers that approach the topic from the other direction: namely, that metaheuristics determine the hyperparameters for machine learning algorithms. For example [here](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2107.05847) (hyperparameter tuning for supervised ML via evolutional algorithm (among others)) or [here](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-022-04923-7) (hyperparameter tuning for support vector regression via gray wolf optimization) or [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925231220311693) (overview of hyperparamter optimization techniques (also metaheuristics) for machine learning algorithms).

**Background:**

I want to solve optimal power flow problems. When these problems are not too big, I can use "classic" MIP solvers (for example glpk or ipopt) and they find the optimal solution pretty fast. But once these problems grow bigger, time for solving seems to grow exponential (especially for formulations that include binary variables). That's why I considered switching to metaheuristics for solving the optimal power flow optimization problem. However, these meatheuristics need hyperparameter tuning to converge to acceptable solutions. As far as I know this tuning is done by hand so far? So I am looking for a way to automat that hyperparameter tuning. However, I did not find anything so far.

Did I maybe just miss some obvious papers? Or is there an obvious reason why there is no research on this yet?

For example I thought about using reinforcement learning to determine optimal hyperparameters for metaheuristics. A colleague who is more familiar with the field of reinforcement learning said that reinforcement learning only leads to further hyperparameters. The problem is only postponed, so to speak

But I'm not an expert either - in any of the fields. So I hope to maybe get some pointers in the right direction or so.

Comment: You can do hyperparameter tuning with meta-heuristics just as well as you would do with ML, that is try a bunch of parameters and select the best result. Why people don't do it as often as in ML... probably because it's not as easy, the hyperparamters have less intuitive sense.